# Writing my own version of MPI_Allreduce in C - why does my code hang indefinitely?

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to write my own version of MPI_Allreduce in C, but only for sizes of power two, i.e. size = 2,4,8,16,... and only for MPI_INT datatype. My code thus far is:

```
 72 int tree_allreduce(const int *sendbuf, int *recvbuf, int count, MPI_Op op, MPI_Comm comm){
 73 
 74   // Create variables for rank and size
 75   int rank, size;
 76   MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);
 77   MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size);
 78 
 79   // While size is greater than 1 there is 2 or more ranks to operate on
 80   while(size > 1){  // While loop active until size=1 when only process remaining is rank 0
 81     if(rank < size){  // Filter out odd ranks which are always bigger than size after sending their data to their left even recvbuffer
 82       if( (rank % 2) != 0 ){ // If rank is odd
 83         MPI_Send(sendbuf, count, MPI_INT, rank-1, rank, comm);  // Send contents of the sendbuf to the recvbuf, using rank of odd process as tag
 84         rank *= size;  // multiplying odd ranks by sizes ensures they are always > or = size when the if(rank < size) comes from next while iteration
 85       }
 86       else{  // If rank is even
 87         // For an even rank, the values for the even number is stored in sendbuf, and the values of the odd rank is stored in recvbuf.
 88         MPI_Recv(recvbuf, count, MPI_INT, rank+1, rank+1, comm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);  // Receive contents of sendbuf from rank+1 into recvbuf
 89         rank /= 2;  // Half the rank so for next iteration of while loop rank 0 --> rank 0, rank 2 --> rank 1, rank 4 --> rank 2, etc...
 90         MPI_Reduce_local(sendbuf, recvbuf, count, MPI_INT, op);  // Use MPI_Reduce_local to do SUM/PROD/MIN/MAX operations and return result into recvbuf
 91       }
 92     }
 93     size /= 2;  // Half the size to reflect the processes contracting pairwise
 94   }
 95 
 96   // Broadcast result back to all processes
 97   MPI_Bcast(recvbuf, count, MPI_INT, 0, comm);
 98 
 99   return 0;
100 }
```

Which works fine for size 2, however for any greater size the code hangs indefinitely and I cannot seem to figure out why. I think I am making some kind of newbie MPI mistake so please let me know where I have gone wrong here.

Comment: the line `rank *= size` looks very strange to me.

Comment: What does stepping through the code with your debugger tell you? At which point does it hang? What are the values of `count` and `rank` and `size` when it hangs?

Comment: It looks very strange to me too, however I can't find a better way to *remove* the odd ranks once they've sent their data to their rank-1 even ranks. The purpose of that line is to, for example in a size = 8 instance, make rank=5 become rank=40 so that it is ignore in the next iteration of the while loop. The line rank /= 2 is it's even counterpart - it makes, for example, rank 6 become rank 3 in the next iteration (after it has operated on the data of rank 7).

Comment: From the second iteration, the active ranks (try to) communicate with the wrong peers.

Comment: Use rank and vrank (virtual rank) instead.

Comment: Insert `printf` everywhere and trace the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have 8 processors (`rank var` is stored in your variable `rank`, `rank acrual` is an actual worker rank).

```
rank var   |01234567
rank actual|01234567
```

First iteration works fine, data is sent according the to scheme

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rcv(1) | snd(0) | rcv(3) | snd(2) | rcv(5) | snd(4) | rcv(7) | snd(6) |

After that you remove odd workers via line `rank *= size`, and update rank vars `rank /= 2`

```
rank var   |0_1_2_3_
rank actual|01234567
```

At the next iteration data is sent according to the scheme

| 0 | - | 2 | - | 4 | - | 6 | - |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rcv(1) | - | snd(0) | - | rcv(3) | - | snd(2) | - |

As you can see, it's messed up. Workers wait for data that is not being send to them.